# preprocessing in R

Tags: string, r, preprocessor

I have a string for example string A="however". Now my I have a variable alpha whose value keeps changing like alpha="er","ho","er",etc.I want to remove this alpha value from the string

when the value of alpha is "er" the final value should be "however"-"er"="howev" and when the value of alpha is "ho" the final value should be "however"-"ho"="wever" and so on.How can I extract this final string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A <- "however" 
alpha <- c("er","ho")
sapply(alpha, gsub, "", A)
#     er      ho    
# "howev" "wever"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually found its very easy

```
gsub(alpha,"",A)
```

would do it

Answer (score 1):

You may use package `stringr`. Function `str_replace` will do the trick.

```
library(stringr)
A<-c("however", "evermore")
alpha <- "er"
str_replace(string=A, pattern=alpha, replacement="")
```

You may also substitute the substring you are removing by anything you put in `replacement`